# Difference between mouse data received from SDL_GetRelativeMouseState and SDL_PollEvent(&event)

Tags: sdl

What is the difference between mouse position data received from  `SDL_GetRelativeMouseState()` and `SDL_PollEvent()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the same difference that there exists between [`SDL_GetRelativeMouseState`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRelativeMouseState?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryMouse%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29) and [`SDL_GetMouseState`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetMouseState?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryMouse%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29).

The former works as though `x` and `y` are:

> set to the mouse deltas since the last call to SDL_GetRelativeMouseState() or since event initialization

The latter works as though `x` and `y` are:

> set to the mouse cursor position relative to the focus window for the currently selected mouse

Note that events usually come with both the position relative to the active window and the delta with the last known position.